# Multiple classes on same parent element not working at the same time: BEM

Tags: html, css, bem

I have two classes on the header: `.header-container` & a theme class, for example `solid-green` or `solid-blue`.

The current markup works correctly in terms of applying the relevant theme styles, but I want to use BEM, so the all of the CSS should be wrapped in the `header-container` class:

```
.header-container {
  // all component styles
}
```

```css
.top-banner {
  height: 70px;
}

.main-banner {
  height: 140px;
}

.solid-green {
  .top-banner {
    background-color: green;
  }
  
  .main-banner {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
}

.solid-blue {
  .top-banner {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  
  .main-banner {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header-container solid-green">
  <div class="top-banner">Top banner</div>
  <div class="main-banner">Main banner</div>
</header>
```

However, when I wrap the CSS with the `header-container` class, the theme class no longer work. Can anyone advise where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header-container {
  .top-banner {
    height: 70px;
  }
  
  .main-banner {
    height: 140px;
  }

  &.solid-green {
    .top-banner {
      background-color: green;
    }
    
    .main-banner {
      background-color: lightgreen;
    }
  }
  
  &.solid-blue {
    .top-banner {
      background-color: blue;
    }
    
    .main-banner {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
  }
}
```